# Configuring a NAS on ESXi Ver 4

Tags: network-attached-storage, vmware-esxi

I finally got ESXi working on my server, and multiple virtual machines... but now, of course I need more storage space.

From what I am reading I am able to attach a NAS device?  They seem to be much cheaper than SANS.... is there any advice as to what type I should get?  How should it be configured?

thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

As fast disks as possible(1 SATA/VM for decent speed) - 2 vms / SAS disk(might get a bit slow tough)

NFS or iSCSI support(ESX supports NFS, iSCSI and FibreChannel as i recall)

4-8 disk nases is what I would look at.

I would check out the 
[Drobo NAS](http://drobo.com/windows/) as it has support for iSCSI and lotsa slots for disks.

Answer (score 1):

We have a NAS setup with NFS configured with ESX v4 and running VMs. If you are going down this route, here are a few tips:

- Have redundant NICs for NFS traffic and a pretty good backbone back into your NAS (we use dedicated gigE). You can also configure a vSphere host with a dedicated NIC for storage traffic.
- vSphere gets finicky with misbehaving mounts. If you lose connectivity to a NFS share for whatever reason, the mounts may go offline and the only way to bring them back online is by a host reboot, recreating the mount from scratch, or running some command line Vmware scripts on the console - could not get do it from the GUI.

[This post](http://communities.vmware.com/message/998849;jsessionid=BEF93BF9A1619AE9DA1F727BE6337C1F) has some interesting discussions on parameter settings for ESX 3.5 and NFS mounts  - you may want to check if some of these are applicable.

Other than that, works pretty well for hosting VMs, snapshots and vmotion.

Hope that helps,
Bruno.